# Why JavaScript Array Map function doesn't execute on the result returned by Array(n)?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I just want to get some more clarity over how map function works and also Array(n) method.

- For relevance lets take two variables **bucket** and **basket**.

```
var bucket = Array(3);                      // Create an empty array of length of 3.
console.log(bucket);                        // Console shows > [null, null, null]
bucket.map((bucketItem, index)=>{           // Trying to run map method over bucket array
    console.log(index, bucketItem);         // Does not enter this scope.
});

var basket = [null, null, null];            // Create an empty array of length of 3.
console.log(basket);                        // Console shows > [null, null, null]
basket.map((basketItem, index)=>{           // Trying to run map method over basket array
    console.log(index, basketItem);         // Console shows > 0 null, 1 null, 2 null 
});

console.log(Array.isArray(bucket))          // Console shows > true, stating bucket is an array.
console.log(Array.isArray(basket))          // Console shows > true, stating basket is an array.
```

Now as shown above bucket and basket both return true, when checked for being an array but however **map** method doesn't execute for **bucket** variable, while it does for **basket**.

- Now lets create a new variable **newBucket** using **Array(n)** method and **... Spread Operator**.

```
var newBucket = [...Array(3)];              // Create an empty array of length of 3 and use it with spread opertor.
console.log(newBucket);                     // Console shows > [null, null, null]
newBucket.map((newBucketItem, index)=>{     // Trying to run map method over newBucket array
    console.log(index, newBucketItem);      // Console shows > 0 undefined, 1 undefined, 2 undefined 
});

console.log(Array.isArray(newBucket))       // Console shows > true, stating newBucket is an array.
```

However the **map** function now executes for **newBucket** and still **newBucket** is a valid array.

Could anyone please guide me on this front or share relevant link or point out materials for the same?

Thanking You,
Sharat

[Here is the link to the code](https://es6console.com/k4bdux4v/)

Comment: It's not because you are using react that this is a react related question

Answer (score 1):

Most of the Array iteration methods don't call the callback for elements that have never been assigned a value. That's the case for the elements of an array that's just been created via `new Array(3)`.

You can use `.fill()` method to initialize all elements of a new array. When you use spread syntax, that *will* pay attention to the uninitialized elements, and so you end up with another new array with elements explicitly initialized to `undefined`.

Comment: Thank you for your kind explanation, precise and to the point.